# error during Codeigniter view execution

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am learning Codeigniter MVC framework. While trying to run a simple program I am getting error related to foreach loop in View. Can anyone please help me?

```
class HomeController2 extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index(){

     $this->load->model('HomeModel2');
     $data['record']=$this->HomeModel2->getdata();

     $this->load->view('HomeView2',$data);
    }
}

class HomeModel2 extends CI_Model
{
    public function getdata(){
        $query=$this->db->get('studen');
        return $query->result();
    }
}

foreach ($record as $ray) {
echo $ray->ID." ".$ray->NAME" ";
}
```

Comment: The code looks incomplete, also, what error are you getting? Indent your code 4 spaces to format as code.

Comment: you lost a point between NAME and qoute/ should be `$ray->NAME . " ";`

Comment: Is there syntax error? change this `echo $ray->ID." ".$ray->NAME." ";` you are missing one `.`